N-Body simulator in Rust implementing Barnes Hut and Leapfrog
I have written a N-body simulator in Rust implementing Barnes Hut algorithm and Leapfrog integrator.
My code seems to work fine, but I'd like to review on techniques which can improve performance while having the code be idiomatic rust. Ideally I'd like to know if there is something that would make it faster (6fps on my laptop) with higher number of particles without resorting to parallelism or GPU compute.
The code below has removed all rendering process to facilitate easy reading, but full code including rendering can be found here
main.rs:
use glam::f32::Vec2;
use std::error::Error;
use rand::distributions::{Distribution,Uniform};

const WIDTH: u32 = 512;
const HEIGHT: u32 = 512;
const N: usize = 50_000;
const GRAV: f32 = 1.; // gravitation constant
const THETA: f32 = 0.6; // Parameter affected both quality and speed. Too high, quality is low, too low fps is low
const SOFTENING: f32 = 10.; // softening parameter based on wikipedia article on nbody
// phi = -Gm/(r*r + e*e).sqrt(), where e is softening parameter
const M: f32 = 1e4; // mass of central body

#[derive(Clone,Copy)]
struct Particle {
    mass: f32,
    r: Vec2,
    v: Vec2,
    field: Vec2,
    field_prev: Vec2,
    first_iter: bool 
}
// First iteration of a particle requires a different step in both leapfrog and Verlet integral.

impl Default for Particle{
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self{
            mass: 1.,
            r: Vec2::ZERO,
            v: Vec2::ZERO,
            field: Vec2::ZERO,
            field_prev: Vec2::ZERO,
            first_iter: true,
        }
    }
}

// An enum for quad tree, either holds a final node with Some(index of particle) or None
// or Branch, which is 4 quadrants within it
enum QuadTree{
    Leaf(Option<usize>),
    Branch([Box<QuadNode>; 4]),
}

// Metadata associated with Quadtree, such as position, width, height, mass contained within the
// node, total_mass*center_of_mass and quadtree itself
struct QuadNode {
    top_left: Vec2,
    width: f32,
    height: f32,
    mass: f32,
    center_of_mass_sum: Vec2,
    qt: QuadTree,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let uradius = Uniform::from(20.0..100.);
    let utheta = Uniform::from(-std::f32::consts::PI..std::f32::consts::PI);
    let mut now = std::time::Instant::now();

    let mut particles : Vec<Particle> = Vec::new();
    particles.push(Particle{mass:M, r:Vec2{x: (WIDTH/2) as f32, y:(HEIGHT/2) as f32}, ..Default::default()});
    // Make N random particles spread around center
    for _ in 1..=N{
        let r = uradius.sample(&mut rng);
        let t = utheta.sample(&mut rng);
        let v = (GRAV*M/r).sqrt(); // for stable orbits
        particles.push(Particle {
            mass: 1.,
            r: Vec2 {
                x: (WIDTH / 2) as f32 + r*t.cos(),
                y: (HEIGHT / 2) as f32 + r*t.sin()
            },
            v: Vec2{
                x: -v*t.sin(),
                y: v*t.cos(),
            },
            // r is perpendicular to v
            ..Default::default()
        });
    }


    // Used for deltatime, simulating 60fps
    let dt = 1./60.;

    loop {
            // Initialise the root node
            let mut root = QuadNode {
                top_left: Vec2::ZERO,
                width: WIDTH as f32,
                height: HEIGHT as f32,
                center_of_mass_sum: Vec2::ZERO,
                mass: 0.,
                qt: QuadTree::Leaf(None),
            };

            // build tree
            for i in 0..particles.len(){
                // If particle is not within the screen, respawm it as a new particle somewhere inside. Doesn't describe any physical phenomenon, but done to have working tree
                if !(0. < particles[i].r.x && particles[i].r.x < WIDTH as f32 && 0. < particles[i].r.y && particles[i].r.y < HEIGHT as f32){
                    let r = uradius.sample(&mut rng);
                    let t = utheta.sample(&mut rng);
                    particles[i].r = Vec2 {x: (WIDTH / 2) as f32 + r*t.cos(), y: (HEIGHT/2) as f32 + r*t.sin()};
                    particles[i].v = Vec2{x: -r/100.*t.sin(), y: r/100.*t.cos()};
                    particles[i].field = Vec2::ZERO;
                    particles[i].first_iter = true;
                }
                // Try adding the particle to root
                put(&mut root, i, &particles);
            }

            for i in 0..particles.len(){
                calculate_field(&root, i, &mut particles);
            }
            for i in 0..particles.len(){
                // using particles[i].v = particles[i].field*dt returns an error, telling to use a
                // local variable, so instead handle each field
                if !particles[i].first_iter{
                    particles[i].v.x += dt/2. * (particles[i].field_prev.x + particles[i].field.x);
                    particles[i].v.y += dt/2. * (particles[i].field_prev.y + particles[i].field.y);
                }
                else{
                    particles[i].first_iter = false;
                }
                // TODO: Decide if it is efficient to have a bool check everytime despite the
                // fact only checking once is needed. Otherwise make a separate first run outside the loop just
                // for this(but then code duplication)
                particles[i].field_prev = particles[i].field;
                particles[i].field = Vec2::ZERO;
                particles[i].r.x += particles[i].v.x * dt + particles[i].field.x/2. * dt * dt;
                particles[i].r.y += particles[i].v.y * dt + particles[i].field.y/2. * dt * dt;
            }
            println!("{}", now.elapsed().as_secs_f32().recip());
            now = std::time::Instant::now();
        }
}

fn put(node: &mut QuadNode, i: usize, particles: &Vec<Particle>) {
    let p = particles[i];
    match &mut node.qt {
        QuadTree::Leaf(particle) => {
            node.center_of_mass_sum += p.mass*p.r;
            node.mass += p.mass;
            match particle.take() {
                // If the leaf is empty, simply add particle
                None => {
                    node.qt = QuadTree::Leaf(Some(i));
                },
                // If the leaf is occupied, split it into quadrants and to individual quad
                // The quadtree associated with the node becomes a branch
                Some(u) => {
                    node.qt = QuadTree::Branch([
                        Box::new(QuadNode {top_left: Vec2 {x: node.top_left.x + node.width / 2., y: node.top_left.y                    },width: node.width / 2.,height: node.height / 2.,center_of_mass_sum:Vec2::ZERO, mass: 0.,qt: QuadTree::Leaf(None)}),
                        Box::new(QuadNode {top_left: Vec2 {x: node.top_left.x,                   y: node.top_left.y                    },width: node.width / 2.,height: node.height / 2.,center_of_mass_sum:Vec2::ZERO,mass: 0.,qt: QuadTree::Leaf(None)}),
                        Box::new(QuadNode {top_left: Vec2 {x: node.top_left.x,                   y: node.top_left.y + node.height / 2. },width: node.width / 2.,height: node.height / 2.,center_of_mass_sum:Vec2::ZERO,mass: 0.,qt: QuadTree::Leaf(None),}),
                        Box::new(QuadNode {top_left: Vec2 {x: node.top_left.x + node.width / 2., y: node.top_left.y + node.height / 2. },width: node.width / 2.,center_of_mass_sum:Vec2::ZERO,height: node.height / 2.,mass: 0.,qt: QuadTree::Leaf(None)}),
                    ]);
                    put(node, u, particles);
                    put(node, i, particles);
                }
            }
        },
        // check which leaf in branch has the coordinates required to fit in the particle, and try
        // putting in it
        QuadTree::Branch(branch) => {
            if      branch[0].top_left.x < p.r.x && p.r.x < branch[0].top_left.x + branch[0].width && branch[0].top_left.y < p.r.y && p.r.y < branch[0].top_left.y + branch[0].height  {put(&mut branch[0], i, particles);}
            else if branch[1].top_left.x < p.r.x && p.r.x < branch[1].top_left.x + branch[1].width && branch[1].top_left.y < p.r.y && p.r.y < branch[1].top_left.y + branch[1].height  {put(&mut branch[1], i, particles);}
            else if branch[2].top_left.x < p.r.x && p.r.x < branch[2].top_left.x + branch[2].width && branch[2].top_left.y < p.r.y && p.r.y < branch[2].top_left.y + branch[2].height  {put(&mut branch[2], i, particles);}
            else if branch[3].top_left.x < p.r.x && p.r.x < branch[3].top_left.x + branch[3].width && branch[3].top_left.y < p.r.y && p.r.y < branch[3].top_left.y + branch[3].height  {put(&mut branch[3], i, particles);}
            else {}
        }
    };
}

fn calculate_field(node: &QuadNode, i: usize, particles: &mut Vec<Particle>){
    match &node.qt{
        // empty nodes make no field
        QuadTree::Leaf(None) => {},
        // for a node with single particle, ie leaf, calculate the distance separate
        &QuadTree::Leaf(Some(j)) => {
            if i!=j{
                let r:Vec2 = particles[j].r - particles[i].r;
                let d = (r.length_squared()+SOFTENING*SOFTENING).sqrt();
                let m = particles[j].mass;
                let field = GRAV*m*r/d/d/d;
                particles[i].field += field;
            }
        },
        // if its a branch, either check if the condition for approximation holds true, or recursve
        // through the tree until all particles are included
        QuadTree::Branch(branch) => {
            let m = node.mass;
            let r:Vec2 = node.center_of_mass_sum/m - particles[i].r;
            let d = (r.length_squared() + SOFTENING*SOFTENING).sqrt();
            let s = node.width;
            if s/d <= THETA {
                particles[i].field += GRAV*m*r/d/d/d;
            }
            else {
                // loop unrolling?
                calculate_field(&branch[0], i, particles);
                calculate_field(&branch[1], i, particles);
                calculate_field(&branch[2], i, particles);
                calculate_field(&branch[3], i, particles);
            }
        },
    }
}


Cargo.toml:

[package]
name = "nbody"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
glam = "*"
rand = "*"

